# How to restart SQL Server Instance after restore master

Tags: backup, restore, sql-server-2019, system-databases, master-system-database

At work we have a productive SQL Server working, and we create backups of each database periodically, including system databases master, msdb and model.

I'm trying to restore the whole datawarehouse into another SQL Server instance as a test, to write documentation in case of total loss. I was able to restore the datawarehouse databases, msdb and model, but the problem started when I restored master.

I restored it in single-user mode, `with replace` and it worked, but then my SQL Server instance stopped and now I can't restart it.

It says something like 'request error or the service did not response in time'.
I've checked the log folder and here's a part of the error message:

> Service Master Key could not be decrypted using one of its encryptions. See sys.key_encryptions for details.
> An error occurred during Service Master Key initialization. SQLErrorCode=33095, State=8, LastOsError=0.

And

> Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error

For each of the databases.

Is a restore of the master database necessary or can I pass on it?
What will I lose?

Hope you guys can help me with this issue, and sorry for my English.

Comment: If you restore `master` you often need to backup/restore the SMK also. Try rebuilding `master` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16#rebuild-system-databases-for-an-instance-of-sql-server and then restore the SMK, then try restore `master` again.

Comment: I've checked for SMK in my SQL Server executing "SELECT * FROM sys.certificates" and "SELECT * FROM sys.simmetric_keys" and it returns empty tables. Should I create a SMK or how can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: SMK will not be in either of those places. The SMK is stored in the registry, it always exists. You can regenerate it using `ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY REGENERATE` but that probably won't help your issue. You need to back it up and restore as mentioned.